# Do all unitary representations weakly converge to zero at infinity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, ergodic-theory, hilbert-spaces

> **Question**. Let $G$ be a non-compact, finite dimensional Lie group, and let $(X, \mu)$ be a [Radon measure space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure). Let $$\rho\colon G\to U(L^2(X))$$
>   be a unitary, strongly continuous, representation. Is it true that, if $g_n\to \infty$, then
>   $$
> \int_X \overline{h(x)}\rho_{g_n} f(x)\, d\mu\to 0, \qquad \forall f, h\in L^2(X)?$$
>   Appropriate hypotheses on $X$ may be assumed.

Here, $g_n\to \infty$ means that, for any compact $K\subset G$, $g_n\notin K$ for all sufficiently big $n\in\mathbb N$.

> **EDIT** (for reference). I learned in the comments that a fairly complete answer is given by the "Howe-Moore vanishing theorem". I found a reference in [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/ergodic-theory-and-topological-dynamics-of-group-actions-on-homogeneous-spaces/D44A57C1D660059C5C4AA7FA8E244659) (Bekka - Mayer, "Ergodic theory and topological dynamics of group actions on homogeneous spaces"); it is Theorem 1.1 at page 81.

---

This property is true in the following cases.

1. $G=(\mathbb R^n, +)$, $X=\mathbb R^n$ with Lebesgue measure and $\rho_g f(x):=f(x-g)$.
2. $G=(\mathbb R_{>0}, \cdot)$, $X=\mathbb R^n$ with measure $d\mu=\frac{dx}{\lvert x\rvert^n}$, and $\rho_g f(x):=f(x/g)$.
3. $G=SU(1, 1)$, $X=\mathbb D$, the unit disk, with measure $d\mu=\frac{4dxdy}{(1-(x^2+y^2)^2)^2}$, and $$\rho_g f(z):=f\left(\frac{az+b}{\overline b z + \overline a}\right), \qquad g=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ \overline b & \overline a\end{bmatrix}, $$ where $|a|^2-|b|^2=1$.
4. $G=SL(2, \mathbb R)$, $X=\mathbb H=\{z\in \mathbb C\ :\ \Im z>0\}$, with measure $d\mu=\frac{1}{y^2}dxdy$, and $$\rho_g f(z):=f\left(\frac{az+b}{c z + d}\right), \qquad g=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}, $$ where $ad-bc=1$. This case is actually isomorphic to the previous one, via the Cayley transform $z\mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ that maps $\mathbb H$ onto $\mathbb D$.

[I learned the proof for the example 2 in this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/805982/8157). The same idea works for the other examples, and it is even slightly simpler; indeed, in all three cases, for all $f\in L^2(X)$, and for all compact $A\subset X$, $$\lVert \rho_{g_n} f\rVert_{L^2(A)}\to 0, $$ provided that $g_n\to \infty$.$^{[1]}$ Thus,
$$
\left\lvert \int_X \overline{h(x)}\rho_{g_n}f(x)\, d\mu\right\rvert \le \lVert h\rVert_{L^2(A)}\lVert \rho_{g_n}f\rVert_{L^2(A)}+ \lVert h\rVert_{L^2(X\setminus A)}\lVert \rho_{g_n}f\rVert_{L^2(X\setminus A)}. $$ 
The first summand tends to zero, while the second can be made arbitrarily small by choosing a sufficiently big $A$, because $h\in L^2(X)$. Here we use that $\rho$ is unitary.

---

$^{[1]}$ As mentioned, this case is slightly simpler than the dilation one, because for the dilation group we must also consider the possibility that the $L^2$ norm concentrates at the origin.

Comment: One needs to obviously exclude the trivial representation.
At any case, for simple Lie groups (and semisimple with appropriate additions) you have the famous Howe-Moore theorem (your example is essentially SL2)
For compact groups, the answer is negative, representations are finite dimensional in this case and tend to have almost periodic nature.
This can be easily seen in the representations of $SO(2)$ on itself, and taking say a trig. polynomial.

Comment: What about $G = \mathbb{R}$, $X= \mathbb{C}$, and $\rho_g f(z) = f(e^{2\pi i g}z)$, i.e., $\rho$ rotates by an angle of $g$? Then $\rho_g = {\rm id}$ whenever $g$ is an integer, so it can't go to zero at infinity.

Comment: @Asaf he said that $G$ is noncompact.

Comment: @NikWeaver, one may take easy modifications, say semisimple with compact factors etc.

Comment: @Asaf: Of course, the $SU(1, 1)$ example is exactly the action of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ on the hyperbolic plane, up to a Cayley transform, like you say. Thank you for pointing me to the Howe-Moore theorem.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: It seems from your examples you are interested in representations sending $f$ to $f(\phi_g(x))$ times eventually some weight to have unitarity. Here $\phi_g$ is a transformation of the space $X$. In this case, your question belongs to ergodic theory. Look up, in particular, the notion of mixing.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: Thank you, that is the most important piece of advice that I obtained from asking this question. I must admit that I had no idea that ergodic theory had something to do with these things.

Comment: The most studied situation from the ergodic theory point of view is when you restrict to a one-parameter subgroup in $G$ (notion of mixing for a flow or continuous time dynamical system) or when you look at $\rho_{g^n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (notion of mixing for a transformation or discrete time dynamical system). As I am not an expert in the area, I don't know if there are results for more complicated group actions with $G$ other than $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, mixing can be stated in terms of vanishing of matrix coefficients defined by the Coopman-von-Nuemann representation of the dynamical system (which is a fancy way of considering $L^{2}(X)$ with the action induced from the measure-preserving transformation). 
The Howe-Moore theorem implies that for say simple Lie group actions, the action is mixing (and further refinements by works of Harish-Chandra, Kazhdan and Oh quantify this decay).

A suitable notion to consider here is joinings (by Furstenberg) and Kronecker factors, as those are the obstacles for mixing.

Comment: @Asaf: It might be worth expanding on your comment and post an answer. Nick gave a counterexample for the wanted property in the most general setting, whereas what you metioned gives positive results in the direction of what the OP seems to be after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are simple counterexamples. E.g., take $G = \mathbb{R}$ and $X = \mathbb{C}$ with Lebesgue measure, and define $\rho_t f(z) = f(e^{2\pi i t}z)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f \in L^2(\mathbb{C})$. Then $\rho_t$ is the identity for any integer $t$, so $\rho_n \to {\rm id}$ strongly, not to zero.

Comment: So, requiring $G$ to be noncompact isn't really effective, because one can take a quotient which is compact.

Comment: @NateEldredge, for non-abelian non-compact semi-simple groups, there are rarely compact quotients which are groups. That's partly why Nik's counterexample may  not quite be decisive, depending what one is really wanting.

Comment: This counterexample does answer my question, and I have learned something.Thank you! I also see, thanks to Asaf, that there is literature concerning this; it goes under the name of "Howe-Moore property".

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Or $G$ the reals, $X$ a singleton, $\mu$ the unit mass on it, $\rho$ *any* unirrep on $L^2(X)=\mathbf C$ (= any character of $G$).

Comment: @paulgarrett: I posted an answer, with a little bit of discussion on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments to Nik's answer, Nate Eldredge and Paul Garrett point out that the answer is not "truly noncompact"; indeed, in that answer the noncompact group $(\mathbb R, +)$ factors through $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. However, we can easily fix this and construct a "truly noncompact" counterexample, by adding a toroidal component with a dense linear flow.

Precisely, let $X=\mathbb T^2\times \mathbb C$ with Lebesgue measure, where $\mathbb T^2=\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$. Let $v=(\alpha, \beta)\in\mathbb R^2$ be such that 
$$\tag{1}\frac\beta\alpha\text{  is irrational, }$$ 
and define a unitary representation of $(\mathbb R, +)$ by 
$$
\rho_t f(x, z):=f(x-tv, e^{-it}z), \qquad \forall f\in L^2(\mathbb T^2\times \mathbb C).$$ 
[Since there is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_flow_on_the_torus) $t_n\to \infty$ such that, say, $\lvert t_n v\rvert\le \frac1{100}$, this representation does not vanish at infinity, just like in Nik's answer; but now there is no compact quotient of $\mathbb R$ that $\rho$ factors through.

*Remark*. I considered $\mathbb T^2\times \mathbb C$, instead of just $\mathbb T^2$, to avoid the objection that $\mathbb T^2$ is compact. So, in this example, we have a non-compact group acting on a non-compact space, with an action that cannot be reduced to the one of a compact quotient. This is what I mean by "truly noncompact".

Comment: @NateEldredge: this answer contains a little bit of discussion on your comment.

Comment: I noticed that somebody downvoted, and somebody retracted the up vote. May I ask why?